# MariaDB - search over multiple rows with same id

Tags: mariadb

I have table with three columns in it. First is `product_id` linked to another table, second is `att_id` with link to another table and last one is `val_id` linked to different table.

There are rows with same `product_id` with `val_id` and `att_id` combinations. Every `product_id` can have different number of `val_id` **(as seen in below example)**. Table looks like:

| product_id | att_id | val_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 1 | 7 |
| 78 | 1 | 10 |
| 78 | 1 | 2 |
| 79 | 3 | 2 |
| 79 | 2 | 1 |
| 79 | 2 | 1 |
| 80 | 3 | 2 |
| 80 | 2 | 1 |
| 80 | 1 | 1 |
| 81 | 2 | 2 |
| 81 | 1 | 1 |
| 81 | 2 | 1 |
| 82 | 2 | 1 |
| 82 | 2 | 1 |
| 83 | 2 | 1 |
| 84 | 3 | 2 |
| 85 | 3 | 2 |
| 85 | 2 | 2 |
| 85 | 2 | 1 |

My goal is to select `product_id` where `val_id` is equal to `(1 AND 2)`. There can be more `val_id`s based on user input.

So, expected result from example above should be:

| product_id |
| --- |
| 79 |
| 80 |
| 81 |
| 85 |

I cannot figure it out since every `product_id`, `val_id` combination is in different row.

So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: val_id cannot be equal to 1 and at the same time be equal to 2.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey, on the contrary.  He is looking for the intersection of the products having a val_id of 1 with the products having a val_id of 2, ie. the products having both a val_id 1 and 2.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: Yeah, in English "and" and "or" are sometimes synonyms.  Very frustrating for mathematicians and programmers.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704290/how-to-return-rows-that-have-the-same-column-values-in-mysql?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
select product_id
from test_tbl
where val_id in (1,2) 
group by product_id
having count(distinct val_id) = 2;
```

Result:

| product_id |
| --- |
| 79 |
| 80 |
| 81 |
| 85 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f2acb41820f3d371dfdcaeaf965cbce9)

Comment: Not that it should make any logical difference but `count(distinct val_id)` should never be `> 2`. Maybe want to re-write the `HAVING` clause as `having count(distinct val_id)=2;` for better readability?

Answer (score 3):

```
select product_id
  from test_tbl
  where val_id = 1
intersect
select product_id
  from test_tbl
  where val_id = 2
```

see my earlier comments.

Comment: thanks for your help